# Get list of HDF5 contents (Pandas HDFStore)

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, hdfstore

I have no problem selecting content from a table within an HDF5 Store:

```
with pandas.HDFStore(data_store) as hdf:
    df_reader = hdf.select('my_table_id', chunksize=10000)
```

How can I get a list of all the tables to select from using pandas?

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097925/typeerror-read-hdf-takes-exactly-2-arguments-1-given

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`hdf.keys()` returns a (potentially unordered) list of the keys corresponding to the objects stored in the HDFStore ([link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/pytables.py#L532))

Answer (score 1):

`hdf.keys()` just return the the name of groups or tables,`my_table_id` instead of column names.